# Glitch/Flicker/Blink at the end of each infinite CSS3 animation

Tags: css

Obligatory code, but the jsFiddle is demonstrating the issue exactly. I have a circle that expands and fades out over 3 seconds. Sonar style is my intention. The issue is on completion of the animation it "blinks" quickly then starts over.

See the issue here: http://jsfiddle.net/39MJL/3/

```
@-webkit-keyframes pulsate /* Safari and Chrome */{
    0% {width:150px;height:150px;top:-178px;opacity:0.5;}
    100% {width:900px;height:900px;top:-550px;opacity:0.1;border: 3px solid rgba(192, 61, 29,      .9)}
}
#pulse1 { border-radius:50%;position:relative;height:150px;width:150px;top:-178px;
    opacity:0.3; margin:0 auto;z-index:-1;border:1px solid #da4521;background-color:#DA785A;
    animation: pulsate 3s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: pulsate 3s infinite;
}
```

Has anyone run into this issue before? If you're not seeing the issue with it, do you mind sharing what browser you're using?

EDIT: Added animation support for other browsers on fiddle. Removed ease-out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can figure out, the flicker you're seeing is the `opacity:0.5` being reset as the animation restarts, but before it moves the circle (appearing for one frame).

One possible solution to your problem (perhaps not the most elegant) is to add an extra keyframe and set `height:0px` to get the circle out of the way before the animation restarts.

CSS:

```
@keyframes pulsate {
  0% {width:150px;height:150px;top:-178px;opacity:0.5;}
  90% {width:900px;height:900px;top:-550px;opacity:0.0;border: 3px solid rgba(192, 61, 29, .9)}
  99% {width:900px;height:900px;top:-550px;opacity:0.0;border: 3px solid rgba(192, 61, 29, .9)}
  100% {width:900px;height:0px;top:-550px;opacity:0.0;border: 3px solid rgba(192, 61, 29, .9)}
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/badAdviceGuy/39MJL/17/)** - I also set the keyframes to `opacity:0.0;` so the circle fades out completely. Now you just need to play with opacity levels and keyframe % to get the lookt you wanted.

Comment: Very much appreciated for taking the time to answer this, and find a solution! Especially as I'm sure it was buried. I've come to the conclusion that the opacity animation is done before the position is calculated, giving the effect I seen. This is also a -webkit only issue as far as I know. EDIT: My solution was very similar to yours :)